# Tips for module naming and criteria for grouping files in a directory

Tags: javascript, naming, abstraction, modules

It appeared, that I have in my pet project two abstractions: asset loaders and drawing tasks. For each abstraction I have some classes representing them (currently a single class for drawing task abstraction and factory, which returns new classes, for asset loaders), a store (formerly a manager, but I found it is a bad practice to use "Manager" word in naming) and some other helpers (e.g. decorators). I am thinking how to put all this in a project structure. When I started the project, there was a folder for abstraction itself, separate folder for stores, and another one for helpers. Currently I realized, that this two systems are actually parallel, and hence should be developed separately. So I decided to create to folder for each.

So what I am interesting it:

- How do you split your files in directories:

  - By use
  - By abstraction they describe
  - By language construction types (i.e. classes, functions)
  - Something else
- How do you name them:

  - you use some words, representing it is a group (i.e.
    assetLoadersSystem, assetLoadersUtils ...)
  - you name it as main concept (just assetLoaders directory with the same file in it)

Is there any place I can read about it? I found some interesting chapters in "Clean code" and "Code complete" about variable naming tips. Is there anything like that for my problem?

Comment: What language is this for? Conventions and best practices vary between languages.

Comment: @MartinK I am using JS here, but I think my question is language neutral. Just to mention, I am not asking for camelCase vs snake_case, or something similar. I am more interesting in files grouping logic and how to name those groups after.

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid complex directories structures to begin with. Distributing files across directories for no particular reason has no particular advantage, yet it can have a couple of disadvantages. If all files belong to the same module, I keep them in the same directory. If this leads to directories with so many files, that common file systems may get a problem (e.g. a performance problem), then your module is definitely way too big and this needs to be fixed first.

Sometimes, though, it makes sense to break up a big, complex module into multiple sub-modules. Even if these are not exposed publicly (everything might still be distributed as a single module), each sub-module would get an own directory, which also makes it easy to one day make separate modules out of it. And this shifts your question from "*How do you split your files in directories?*" to "*How do you split your module into sub-modules?*" And apparently, you've already found an answer to that later question. Personally I prefer to break up modules by functionality.

As for the naming, if directories group files of modules or sub-modules together, you should name them like you'd name modules or sub-modules.